# Get node-postgres result into an object outside the callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm re-writing a data profiling script I developed in python in javascript as I'm following along to the Wes Bos beginner Javascript Course.

So this is a console script that takes database connection information as well as a target table as input.  Ultimately, it will execute 9 different queries against each column found in the target table and produce a report.

How can I get the sqlOut available as an object after the pool.query so that I can loop over it etc.

Thanks in advance.

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'pps',
  password: 'XXXX',
  port: 5432,
});

sql = `Select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'profiling_nws6'`;

let sqlOut = [];

pool.query({ text: sql, rowMode: 'array' }, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
  }
  // sqlOut.push(result.rows);
  sqlOut = result.rows.slice(0);
  console.log(typeof sqlOut);
  console.log(Array.isArray(sqlOut));
  // console.log(sqlOut);
  // pool.end();
  return sqlOut;
});

// now I want sqlOut available so I can do various things with the data...

console.log(sqlOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the query

```js
pool.query({ text: sql, rowMode: 'array' }, callback);
```

The callback is executed with results (or error)
But this callback can be execute much later than is your `console.log` (and it is, as pool needs to connect to the database, sent the query, wailt some time, then receive the results of your query, and just then execute yours callback.

You need to get some knowledge about Promises (or Async/Await) which will help you with getting the resources from database.

Comment: Yes, from googling I knew promises or async/await would help, I just assumed there must be a solution with the callback approach as well.  Perhaps not.

Comment: The issue here is, that the return from callback is not used anywhere. And its execution is way after your console.log